# Changing tick type in IB API with Matlab

Tags: matlab, interactive-brokers

I am trying to request real time data using TWS via Matlab's IB API. I don't want regular market data though, specifically I am trying to obtain implied volatility. This is the guide I am using: http://www.mathworks.com/help/trading/ibtws.realtime.html

I should be able to obtain IV just by plaching f='106' according to IB API: https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/software/api/api.htm

But everytime I get the same thing (RTVolume), that is, bid, ask, last etc. I am always getting market data regardless of what the integer ID flag is changed to.

This is my code:

```
try
    close(ib);
    close(conn);
catch

end

clear all;

ibBuiltInRealtimeData = struct('id',0,'BID_PRICE',0,'BID_SIZE',0,'ASK_PRICE',0,'ASK_SIZE',0);

while true

    ib = ibtws('',7496);
    f = '106';

    ibContract = ib.Handle.createContract;
    ibContract.symbol = 'AAPL';
    ibContract.secType = 'STK';
    ibContract.exchange = 'SMART';
    ibContract.primaryExchange = '';
    ibContract.currency = 'USD';

    tickerid = realtime(ib,ibContract,f);

    d2 = ibBuiltInRealtimeData;
    d2

    pause(1);
end
```

And this is the output:

```
        id: 5689.00
 BID_PRICE: 102.55
  BID_SIZE: 1.00
 ASK_PRICE: 103.00
  ASK_SIZE: 1.00
LAST_PRICE: 102.79
 LAST_SIZE: 0
    VOLUME: 434689.00
```

I see no implied volatility anywhere! How can I request real time data of other things besides market data?

Comment: I don't know matlab but if you don't want market data the genericTickList = '106,mdoff' .  Also maybe that struct needs the right ticktype which is OPTION_IMPLIED_VOL = 24, but I don't know how matlab deals with the data.  BTW none of those is from the RTVolume data, that's from requesting  '233' and has no bid or ask.  It also just comes as a string.

Comment: f='106,mdoff' gives me an error and it doesn't even run. The struct was placed there just to initialize it. I am honestly lost, I don't know how to request real time data different from market prices. :/

Comment: mdoff just stands for market data off.  You are supposed to supply a comma separated list.  if '106,233' works then it's a matlab problem maybe.  233 is the RTVolume tick type.  Also, RTV comes back in the tickString event and  I think IV comes back in tickGeneric.  How does matlab implement those?

Comment: I am not so sure actually. The thing is that anything I type (whatever int code) it always returns the same thing. 233 or 100 doesn't make a difference, the same output I get everytime.

Comment: that's the regular market data, the only way to not get it is adding 'mdoff'.  It doesn't matter, you can just ignore it.  The problem is finding out how to see the extra data.

Comment: Are you using some code like [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29434-connecting-to-interactive-brokers-via-activex-api/content/CTws.m](this?)  Notice that it ignores the other ticktypes.  It alos ignores volume = 8, which you get.   Also generic ticks won't work with a snapshot quote, I don't know what realtime() does.

Comment: I am not so sure about what realtime does neither, I am just following the tutorials of Matlab's trading toolbox. So not using the code like that, just using what comes with my Matlab (which is the trading toolbox).

Comment: I look at the docs for the toolbox and you're using the wrong function call.  Notice lower on the page you have to write your own event handler for generictick '233' and call realtime with 4 arguments, the last being @eventhandler.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/trading/ibtws.realtime.html

Comment: I finally found the solution!! I edited the realtime function that comes within the @ibtws object in the trading toolbox libraries. In the line defining event names the tick type "tickGeneric" was missing so I added it: eventNames = {'tickSize','tickPrice','tickGeneric','tickSnapshotEnd'};

Now it works and I am getting implied volatility! Thanks a lot for your help Brian.

Answer (score 0):

It's an easy explanation but not the one you want to hear:

The contract you're using is a stock and not an option. Like you can read in the [API Manual](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/tick_types.html):

> **Note**: not all tick types are available for all instruments at all times. If you are not receiving a specific tick type when you think you should see if the tick type in question is available within the TWS itself. Remember the TWS API is only a delivery channel: if the information is not available in the TWS itself first, the TWS will not be able to dispatch it via the API socket.

The tick type "*Option Implied Volatility*" (Tick Id 24) is used for options and therefore it's not available for stocks.

Just use another contract and you'll get your expected result.

I hope this helps.